# Import jquery plugin twice in differents divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have my page example.php in which I include Jquery.

```
<html>
   <head>
         [...]
   </head>
   <body>
         [...]
   </body>
   <script src="/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       window.onload = function() {

        $('form').submit(function(){
            $(':submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        })
        // ######## OBTENER LOS REGISTROS ########

        function fetch_data(){
            $.ajax({  
                url: "/select/select_curso.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#mostrar_informacion').html(data);  
                }  
            });  
            $.ajax({  
                url: "/select/select_alumnos_curso.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#mostrar_informacion2').html(data);  
                }  
            }); 
        }  
        fetch_data();
        });

    };
 </script>
```

As you can see I bring some data (a table ) in two different divs. In each one of those divs I need to use the same Jquery. So in those files (select_curso.php and select_alumno_curso) I import again :

```
    //SELECT_CURSO.PHP

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover js-basic-example dataTable" id="example">
             [...]
    </table>
    <script src="/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Doing that is causing me some problems. Is there a form to share the Jquery of the principal file "example.php" to "select_curso.php" because I need jquery in order to the tables of bootstrap work

Comment: you should only have to import jquery once, at the top of your current page.

Comment: you don't need to "import" jQuery in the php files you get data from _at all_. As @Icewine already said, import it once on top of your main page.

Comment: The code you've got there is outside a script tag, it won't execute.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the PHP `include()` function, which can import one page's DOM into another page. Essentially, you should have a `header.php` file that contains things such as your site title, so you don't have to re-define it all the time. This header file should also include any scripts that your site is reliant on, such as jQuery. jQuery should **only** be imported once, and making use of a header file that gets included on every page will allow you to use it on every page while only importing it once.

Comment: I already import it only in the top of my main page but it does work. My bootstrap table that is in the "select_curso.php" says that it needs Jquery. What is the difference between importing Jquery in the top or in the bottom of the main file?